# Relation _unknown error in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

field definition:

```py
department_id = fields.Many2one('partner.department',string="Department", compute="_get_product_department",store=True,required=True)
```

view definition:

```xml
<field name="department_id"  />
```

ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT "_unknown"."id" as "id" FROM "_unknown"

Comment: Does model `partner.department` really exist?

Comment: ya,.... its my own model

Comment: i solved this problem, partner.department model is another module so i added  that module name into __manifest__.py,depends

Comment: was about to say that why why why LooooL, I had this error when i started to learn odoo offffffff take me a day to figure it out nice work

Comment: oh...k for me also this issue take day... any way problem solved ...

Answer (score 1):

Things which you can check are
1.) put the relation module in depends.
2.) Upgrade the module of which you are trying to add relation.

In my case my issue was resolved when i upgraded the module which was of M2O relation.

Lets say my custom.model is in module named 'my_module'

eg.) dept = fields.Many2one('custom.model', 'Relation Example')

I upgraded my_module and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem, **partner.department** model is another module so i added that module name into manifest.py file in depend section..